# Image full length of page

Tags: html, css

I would like an image to be the full width of the page aka 100% rather than the 70% set in .body - I've tried adding a padding, and also tried:

```
body image{ width:100%} 

--------------------------------
body{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

.body{
    background-color:green;
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.mainHeader img{
    width:100%;
    margin:0% 2%;
}
```

[http://imgur.com/a/t6fYD](https://imgur.com/a/t6fYD)

The photo displays how the image is currently displaying - highlighted in white, and shows how id like it displayed - in black. It's currently displaying at 70%.

Comment: `body image{` is a typo? Should be `body img {`

Comment: yeah i separated that from my current css - that was just an attempt i done, gave them img a class ="image"

Comment: @James, if your img has a class of image then your CSS should look like this: .image{width:100%}.. Look at my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
body img{ 
width:100%
} 

--------------------------------
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
}
```

Note that the `body img {....}` is correct.

If your `img` has a class of `image` as you suggested, then your CSS should look like this:

```
.image{ 
width:100%
} 

--------------------------------
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
}
```

EDIT:

In the fiddle that you have provided in the comments below, you have this:

```
.body{
    background-color:green;
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

This is wrong. The `.` can only be used to reference a class name. and `#` can only be used to reference an ID name.

When you try to give some CSS on body or html, you don't need to used `.` or `#`.

So, your code becomes this:

```
body{
    background-color:green;
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

and to make the body 100% width then you simply change the value of `70%` to `100%`.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, you are looking for something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/7nv90v0s/

Comment: Hi David, tried your solution - but it seems to still be sizing to 70% due to .body{ width:70% } despite body{width:100%} and body img{width:100%} like you suggested

Comment: @James, can you please provide a FIDDLE?

Comment: but for your solution you've removed the .body { width:70% } - just to make it clearer I'm trying to emulate something like this homepage: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ -> you can see under their 100% image they have content at ~70%

Comment: @James, if that is what you are trying to achieve then your entire layout is wrong!

Comment: @James, please view the FIDDLE in my last Edit in my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/7nv90v0s/

Answer (score 0):

See this link from w3c school
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp

You can put the image full size like this:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```